# Python: How to import MS excel data into MS access database

Tags: python

**I am trying to do it with the following code and I do not if it is right or not**

```
import pyodbc

DBFile = r'C:\Users\sidhant\Documents\Database1.accdb'

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ='+DBFile)

exfile = r'C:\Users\sidhant\Documents\Sheet1.xlsx'

conn1 = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver \
                       (*.xlsx)};DBQ='+exfile,autocommit=True)

curs1 = conn1.cursor()

excel_results = curs1.execute('select [a_column] from [sheet1$]').fetchall()

curs1.executemany('insert into mytable (mycolumn) values (?)', excel_results)

conn.commit
```

**and it gives me this error**

> C:\Users\sidhant\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/sidhant/PycharmProjects/untitled/practice.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/sidhant/PycharmProjects/untitled/practice.py", line 5, in 
>       conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={access (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ='+DBFile)
>   pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: For Access, there is a special driver you have to install. You need to make sure it matches which ever version of python you have (32 bit vs 64 bit). It's kind of an ass pain

Comment: I downloaded the 32 bit version of jetbrains pycharm and created 32 bit driver but it still gives me error. Can you please double check my string DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;axScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:\Users\sidhant\Documents;DBQ=C:\Users\sidhant\Documents\Database1.mdb

Comment: No i mean there's an Access driver you have to download from microsoft. Google should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Download and install [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). That should take care of it.

Not sure if it matters, but this is the exact string I use

```
'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq='
```

Comment: okay I am installing it. Is the code I provided is right or not ?

Comment: It worked and now the error comes on 10 line which is pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Which version did you download?

Comment: I downloaded both of them. The error is on this line now conn1 = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver \
                       (*.xlsx)};DBQ='+exfile,autocommit=True). First it was on this line conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ='+DBFile).

Comment: Sounds like your issue is now with the excel driver, i don't know much about that